# I want to Intialize object only after user selection, but don't know how?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

```
@page "/sql"
@using MyApp.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS



<div class="choose-form" style="visibility: @(IsBranchSelectionShown ? "visible" : "hidden" )">
    <input type="text" @bind="district.DistrictName" /> <span>:מחוז</span>
     <br /><br />
     <input type="text" @bind="district.PresentationDate" /> <span>:תאריך</span>
    <div class="choose-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick ="InsertData" >בחר</button>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="fetched-data" style="visibility: @(OnScreen ? "visible" : "hidden" )">

    <ul>
        <li>@Handler.DistrictName</li>
        <li>@Handler.PresentationDate</li>
    </ul>

</div>




@code {
    bool IsBranchSelectionShown = true;
    bool OnScreen = false;


    private List<District> MyList = new();
    private District district = new();
    private District Handler = new();



    protected async Task<District> InsertData()

    {

        IsBranchSelectionShown = false;

        using var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<District>("SqlData/Insertion",district);
        var content = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<District>();
        return content;

      

    }

    }
```

When the use chooses 2 parameters, there is a method `InsertData` that is fetching some data that is relying on the chosen data. My question is how to initialize the fetched data?

I tried to use:

```
protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{

      var Handler = InsertData();
}
```

but it does not work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: InsertData is an async method and returns a Task<Direct>. Then when you use `var Handler` a new local variable is used. Use `Handler = await InsertData();` instead of `var Handler = InsertData();`

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of your `"fetched-data"` div is determined by the `OnScreen` boolean value. You can set this to true in `OnInitializedAsync` once the data is loaded:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

   Handler = await InsertData();
   OnScreen = true;
}
```